# What is the difference between the following CSS class definitions?

Tags: css, css-float, anchor

I was reading a tutorial for making a CSS based horizontal dropline menu and I noticed that the anchor element (`<a>`) was set with float:left and `display:block`

I wonder what does this do? Because, when you add `display:block` to an inline element, you can notice the difference, but when you add `float:left` back again, it's almost like not adding anything else.Only a small spaces between two consequtive inline elements vanishes with `float:left`.

So basically what I want to know is, what is the difference between the following classes, when a few anchor elements are placed consequently one after the other:

```
a.one {
    display:block;
    float:left; 
}​

a.two {
    float:left; 
}​

a.default { 
}
```

Comment: The `a` in these examples can be stripped. `#one` is very specific, there can only be one element with id "one" in the document. Also, an element can only have one ID, so all of your selectors always select different elements and cannot interfere with each other. Did you mean `a.one`, `a.two`, `a`?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space between `a` and the class descriptors? `a .one` means the element with class `one` *contained* by an `a` tag, whereas `a.one` means `a` elements with class `one`.

Comment: @Hamish thanks. I have chosen my name wisely, haven't I? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elements that are floated automatically behave like `block` elements (see [W3C definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position)) in terms of the box model (i.e. width, height, margins). So, rules 1 and 2 are equivalent. Floating something and specifying `display` is redundant in most cases (or misleading in this case).

Rule 3 differs because the `a` element is `inline` by default.

Comment: >Floating something and specifying display is redundant (or misleading in this case).
exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Specifying the display will however help in overriding a previous display declaration, like `display:none`. Specifying `float:left;` will not make the element appear, it needs `display:block`. It's probably not the case for this example, but it's certainly possible in real code.